# Error message claims that I am passing two arguments into a function that takes only one

Tags: python, nltk

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-2-word-vectors) on natural language processing in Python. I am structuring the code in a way that I find easier to read.

```
class Datasets(object):
    labeled_training_data = pandas.read_csv(r"G:\Downloads\Kaggle\NLP\labeledTrainData.tsv\labeledTrainData.tsv", 
                        header=0, 
                        delimiter="\t", 
                        quoting=3)
    test_data = pandas.read_csv(r"G:\Downloads\Kaggle\NLP\testData.tsv\testData.tsv", 
                       header=0, 
                       delimiter="\t", 
                       quoting=3)
    unlabeled_training_data = pandas.read_csv(r"G:\Downloads\Kaggle\NLP\unlabeledTrainData.tsv\unlabeledTrainData.tsv", 
                                      header=0, 
                                      delimiter="\t", 
                                      quoting=3)

class TextCleaner(object):
    @classmethod
    def convert_to_word_list(html_text, remove_stopwords = False):
        cleaned_text = BeautifulSoup(html_text).get_text()
        cleaned_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", cleaned_text)

        all_words = cleaned_text.lower().split()

        if remove_stopwords:
            stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
            remaining_words = [word for word in all_words if not word in stop_words]

        return(all_words)

    @classmethod
    def __splitIntoSentences(text, tokenizer, remove_stopwords = False):
        sentences_in_text = tokenizer.tokenize(text.strip())

        non_empty_sentences = []

        for sentence in sentences_in_text:
            if len(sentence) > 0:
                non_empty_sentences.append(__convertToWordList(sentence, remove_stopwords))

        return non_empty_sentences

    @classmethod
    def get_all_sentences_from_training_sets(tokenizer):
        all_sentences = []

        print "Parsing sentences from the labeled training set..."
        for review in Datasets.labeled_training_data["review"]:
            all_sentences.append(TextCleaner.__splitIntoSentences(review, tokenizer))

        print "Parsing sentences from the unlabeled training set..."
        for review in Datasets.unlabeled_training_data["review"]:
            all_sentences.append(TextCleaner.__splitIntoSentences(review, tokenizer))

        print "There are %d sentences in our training sets." % len(all_sentences)

        return all_sentences
```

The problem arises when I run these two lines in the REPL:

```
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
all_sentences = TextCleaner.get_all_sentences_from_training_sets(tokenizer)
```

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: getAllSentencesFromTrainingData() takes exactly 1 argument
>   (2 given)

I have read about `nltk.data.load()` in the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html), but I am still none the wiser about the what causes the error message.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to a `classmethod` should be `cls`, which will be filled (edit: by the Python runtime, not you) with the specific class on which the method is being called.

To be pythonic, though, these look like they really could be module-level functions since they are not using the mechanisms of a class in any way.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you suggesting that I rewrite my code like this? `all_sentences = TextCleaner.get_all_sentences_from_training_sets(TextCleaner, tokenizer)`

Comment: No he didn't say anything like that at all. classmethods *automatically* take the class as the first argument, just as instance methods automatically take the instance, which is why Python is passing two arguments to your methods. But he also said that these should not be methods in the first place. Python is not Java.

Comment: In other words, @MY_G, you should define `get_all_sentences_from_training_sets()` to take the class as an argument.